# How to export each Excel sheet to each page on PDF?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, c#

I want to export specified Excel sheet to specified page on PDF. For example, Sheet1 from Excel to Page1 on PDF. Sheet2 from Excel to Page2 on PDF...so on. I know how to export whole Excel book to PDF but I can't specify which sheet needs to be exported to which page. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: What program are you using to export to pdf?  When I use pdfcreator to export, and I select entire workbook, it automatically puts each worksheet on its own page in the pdf.  If the worksheet is otside the print margins, you highlight the area, and choose page layout - print area - set print area and convert the workbook to pdf and the worksheet will all fit on one page.

Comment: Too late for me to edit my initial comment, but this method also works with Adobe.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no commercial PDF writers installed: If you're using a virtual pdf printer driver such as FoxIt PDF, CutePDF writer or Microsoft own "Print to PDF" (in Windows 10 only), you could print each excel sheet to separate PDF files. And you can third-party freeware (like [this](http://www.freewaregenius.com/split-merge-paginate-or-even-change-the-layout-of-a-pdf-with-hexonic-pdf-split-and-merge/))to combine PDF and paginate accordingly.